# Arduino IDE crashes without any warning

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide

I'm a beginner in arduino. I just installed Arudino IDE (arduino-1.0.5-r2-windows) but when I try to run its not responding and crashes after few minutes. 
I tried re-installing it and removing the temporary files but none of those helped.

Can anyone tell me what causes this problem and how to debug it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing Arduino 1.5.6 solved the issue.